# RxJs share operator and Observable created with range

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to understand why [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) RxJs operator works differently if the source Observable is created with [range](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/range) instead of [timer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer).

Changing the original code to:

```
const source = range(1, 1)
    .pipe(
        share()
    )

const example = source.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('***SIDE EFFECT***')),
    mapTo('***RESULT***'),
)

const sharedExample = example
const subscribeThree = sharedExample.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
const subscribeFour = sharedExample.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

Results in:

> console.log src/pipeline/foo.spec.ts:223
>       ***SIDE EFFECT***
>
> console.log src/pipeline/foo.spec.ts:228
>       ***RESULT***
>
> console.log src/pipeline/foo.spec.ts:223
>       ***SIDE EFFECT***
>
> console.log src/pipeline/foo.spec.ts:229
>       ***RESULT***

Basically, the side effect is invoked more than once.

As far as I know `range` is supposed to be a cold observable but it is said that `share` should turn cold observables to hot.

What is the explanation behind this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to point out.

First, if you look closely at the function signature for `range`, you'll see it takes a third parameter, a `SchedulerLike`.

If unspecified, RxJS calls the `next` handler of each subscriber *immediately* with the relevant value for the `range` observable until it's exhausted. This isn't desirable if you intend to use the `share` operator, because it effectively bypasses any shared side effect processing that might be introduced.

[Relevant snippet taken from the actual implementation:](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/673bf4725cee88d268bca513a70a42c9e2bc5d18/src/internal/observable/range.ts#L53)

```js
// src/internal/observable/range.ts#L53
do {
  if (index++ >= count) {
    subscriber.complete();
    break;
  }
  subscriber.next(current++);
  if (subscriber.closed) {
    break;
  }
} while (true);
```

`timer` also takes an optional `SchedulerLike` argument. If unspecified, the implementation adopts [`AsyncScheduler`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/asyncScheduler) by default, different to the default for `range`.

Secondly, the `share` operator should follow all other operators that might have side effects. If it precedes them, the expected unifying behaviour of pipe operator processing is lost.

So, with both points in mind, to make the `share` operator work with `range` as you're expecting:

```js
const { asyncScheduler, range, timer } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, tap, share } = rxjs.operators;

// Pass in an `AsyncScheduler` to prevent immediate `next` handler calls
const source = range(1, 1, asyncScheduler).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('***SIDE EFFECT***')),
  mapTo('***RESULT***'),
  // All preceding operators will be in shared processing
  share(),
);

const sub3 = source.subscribe(console.log);
const sub4 = source.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, can the general conclusion be that `share` works only for async scheduled observables ? Without providing a scheduler I am not able to turn it into `ConnectableObservable` either, right ? Is there a way to achieve this synchronously (create observable, 1st subscribe, 2nd subscribe and blocking call to start producing events ).

Comment: @dev-null, yes, although if in doubt I'd recommend you check whether the underlying implementation of the observable-generating operator you're using has any nuances about the scheduler it uses by default. Notice if you substitute the scheduler with `QueueScheduler` (documentation describes this as behaving synchronously), you won't get the behaviour you're expecting either.